# in Android detect if a ListView item is clicked

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a `ListView` in a `Fragment` where I need to be able to detect when an item in the ListView is selected. I need the list item to throw a flag or something along those lines so that a method in the Main Activity which houses the Fragments can detect whether or not the ListView was acted upon. I need a method in the Main Activity basically like this:

```
public void doSomething(){
    if(Fragment ListView onItemClick is detected){
        //--- do something
    } else {
        //--- don't do anything
    }
}
```

The `OnItemClickListener` in the Fragment ListView that needs to indicate that it's been acted upon looks like this:

```
list_LV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Cursor getPathCursor = (Cursor) list_LV.getItemAtPosition(position);               
        String cursorSDFStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sdfdate"));
        String cursorCalDateStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("caldate"));
        String cursorURLStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("path"));
        String cursorTitleStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String cursorbodyStr = getPathCursor.getString(getPathCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

        Intent slpI = new Intent("com.myapp.LISTVIDEO");
        slpI.putExtra("SDFKey", cursorSDFStr);
        slpI.putExtra("CalDateKey", cursorCalDateStr);
        slpI.putExtra("PathKey", cursorURLStr);
        slpI.putExtra("TitleKey", cursorTitleStr);
        slpI.putExtra("bodyKey", cursorbodyStr);
        startActivity(slpI);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok whats the problem? in onclick method just call `doSomething()` ?

Comment: Simply call `getActivity()` inside your `onItemClick` to get a reference to this activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the steps google outlined here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

You can alternately use broadcasts or something like Otto http://square.github.io/otto/